# Pairing Bluetooth with a Sony CMT-X3CD Audio System

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Sony CMT-X3CD Audio System which I am trying to pair bluetooth with my Dell Inspiron 15 PC. Not having any luck. Can anyone tell me where I maybe going wrong. I think I may have to install driver but can't find the one

Comment: Please tell us what exactly you did and where reality failed to meet your expectations.

Comment: Also what have you tried so far? When you enter the Pairing mode on your Sony CMT-X3CD Audio System Does it show pairing on the screen? also how far away are you from the unit itself?